# Numpy re-assigning a variable doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find the variables that aren't Numpy array and change them to an Array via the following way:

```
import numpy as np
a = 1
b = np.array([1,2,3])
c = np.array([1,2,3])

for item in a, b, c:
        if type(item) != np.ndarray:
            print(item)
            item *= np.ones(3)
            print(item)
```

The result of the second `print` shows that the variable `a` is changed to array `[1. 1. 1.]` but when I check it, is still `a=1`.
Why? How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have to change `a`?  How about making a new list, eg. `[np.asarray(item) for item in (a,b,c)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `a = 1`, the name `a` is bound to a python `int` object. Python `int`s are immutable. The result of any operation on it is **always** a different object.

Contrary to what the other answers imply, `item is a` is `True` for the first iteration of the loop: both names are bound to the exact same `int` object. The problem is with the line `item *= np.ones(3)`. Remember that the operation returns a new numpy array. The array is then bound to the name `item` regardless of whether the original binding was mutable or not. It does not rebind the name `a` because you never told it to, so `a` still refers to the original `1`.

The most pythonic way to change the values of arbitrarily named variables is to put them in a `dict`:

```
myvars = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': np.array([1,2,3]),
    'c': np.array([1,2,3]),
}
for name in myvars:
    ...
    myvars[name] *= np.ones(3)
    ...
```

This works because the line `myvars[name] *= np.ones(3)` is approximately equivalent to

```
myvars[name] = operator.__imul__(myvars[name], np.ones(3))
```

Notice that the reassignment happens to the correct place regardless of whether `__imul__` returns a new object like for `int` or performs a true in-place operation like for `np.ndarray`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find `atleast_1d` instructive.  First its code:

```
def atleast_1d(*arys):
    res = []
    for ary in arys:
        ary = asanyarray(ary)
        if ary.ndim == 0:
            result = ary.reshape(1)
        else:
            result = ary
        res.append(result)
    if len(res) == 1:
        return res[0]
    else:
        return res
```

With your samples:

```
In [11]: a = 1 
    ...: b = np.array([1,2,3]) 
    ...: c = np.array([1,2,3])
```

It returns a list of arrays, one for each of the inputs:

```
In [12]: np.atleast_1d(a,b,c)                                                                  
Out[12]: [array([1]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

unpacking can then be used to reassign the variables:

```
In [13]: a,b,c = np.atleast_1d(a,b,c)                                                          
In [14]: a                                                                                     
Out[14]: array([1])
```

Since it uses `asanyarray`, the `b` and `c` arrays are not copied (not even views).

It doesn't quite produce what you want, an array of `ones` of the same size as `b` or `c`, but it could be adapted to do that.

Answer (score -1):

The for loop variable `item` is storing the value of `a` during the first loop iteration. Then, when modifying `item`, `a` is not updated since `item` only stores the value of `a` and not a reference of it. In other words, `a` and `item` store the same value but in different memory locations.

Before starting the iteration I would store the variables into a list and do this:

```
import numpy as np
a=1
b = np.array([1,2,3])
c = np.array([1,2,3])
L = [a, b, c]
for i in range(len(L)):
    if type(L[i]) != np.ndarray:
        print(L[i])
        L[i] *= np.ones(3)
        print(L[i])
print(L)
```

When printing `L`, all the elements should be numpy arrays. This occurs because inside the for loop it is accessing to the elements that are inside the list through the reference by the index.

Comment: Your opening paragraph is not right. `a` and `item` are identical references: `a is item` is `True`. The problem is that you reassign `item` but not `a`.